# Update controller parameter from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have a meeting controller and a user controller, I want users to book for meetings from a user show page so I have this piece of code in my user controller

```
#user controller    
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @meeting = Meeting.new
end
```

But I want to update `recipient_id` as soon as the meeting has been created so I tried

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @meeting = Meeting.new
    @meeting.recipient_id = @user.id    
end
```

with the hope that `@meeting.recipient_id = @user.id` would update the recipiend_id with the `@user.id` but that didn't happen.

```
#routes.rb
resources :users do
    post 'meetings', to: 'meetings#create'
end
```

How can I update the meeting recipient ID of the new meeting?

Comment: for updating a record you have to call `update`. IIUC, what you need is to do something like `Meeting.create(recipient_id: @user.id, ... other params)` in the `create` action in the MeetingsController

Comment: But the meeting controller won't know the @user.id of the user whose show page I'm in.

Comment: Can you share the code for `User#show` and perhaps code for your models and routes so that folks can understand the model/relationships and the routes that you have?

Comment: I have updated the question with the User#show and routes

Comment: Do you really want to create a new Meeting object with every call to `show`? That doesn't seem right, or are you just testing?

Comment: I want users to be able to create meetings from another users show page, that is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The `show` method in the UserController is called when the `show` view is being built. But you need to think about which method is called when the user actually asks to create a meeting. Presumably, you have a form on this page, and you need think about which controller runs when that form is submitted. What's the code for that portion of the `show` view?